# linux counting characters then output number of characters in a string entered by user and it also needs a while loop

Tags: linux, string, bash

I have been trying to get linux to count the characters in a string and then out put them i want the user to be able to enter a string and the amount of characters in a string to be outputed however i have a limited understanding of linux so i really need your help thank you!

so far i have got this:

```
#!/bin/bash

x="This is a test"

y="${x//[^s]}"

echo "$y"

echo "${#y}"
```

but that only does it for one type of character and it's not in a while loop that will allow the user to quit if they wan to if you can help it would be appretiated

an example input would be "i like pie"
i would want the program to output "the string you have entered has 10 characters

Comment: Show some example input and expected outputs.

Comment: ok i have done that thank you for telling me what i did wrong it really helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read` to get input from user and then use `${#var}` to get the length:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter some input text: " input
echo "# of chars in input: ${#input}"
```